# Не работает getResources Modx

Tags: modx

В шаблоне делаю вывод

```
[[!getResources&showHidden =`1`&tpl=`cool`&debug=`1`]]
```

и на странице ничего нету. Плагин точно установлен и активирован. В чем может быть еще проблема?

P.S. С modx работаю не давно

Comment: Забыли про `?` при вызове, так: `[[!getResources?...`

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

```
[[!getResources? &showHidden =`1` &tpl=`cool` &debug=`1`]]
```

После знака вопроса передаются параметры, вы забыли его указать.

Answer (score 0):

Установите `pdoTools` и используйте `pdoResource`.
Fenom:

```
{'pdoResource' | snippet : [
 'parent' => '1',
 'tpl' => 'cool'
]}
```